# My excell spreadsheet keeps turning 1/43 into a date.

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have tried to change it to "Gerneral" in the format bar but it changes right back to "Custom". How do I fix this? My intention is to not that this is 1 of 43 boxes not Jan-43

Answer (score 0):

Type an apostrophe first. For example, type `'1/43`. It will interpret it literally as a string, not a number.

Comment: You could also change it to the "Fraction" format

Comment: This has the advantage of working for more than just fractions or other numbers. For example, if you want to print `0001` instead of `1`

Comment: Unfortunately you can't add the cells together properly like this (and it gives that annoying little green triangle in the corner). When trying to add '1/43 in separate cells the result is 31414, which is far from accurate.

Comment: @slow_excellence It wasn't in the original criteria, so it wasn't considered.

Comment: And I gave an alternative that took it into consideration. You never know what changes you may make to a spreadsheet in the future so the more complete you make it, the less you have to revise it.